# itext7: InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.Layout.HtmlPageBreak to type iText.Layout.Element.IBlockElement

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext7, page-break

1. Using itext7 (7.2.0) AND itext7.pdfhtml (4.0.0) AND .Net Core 5.0
2. Converting itext5 report to itext7
3. Getting the error, when forcing a page break using html style 'page-break-before: always;'

   ```
    public FileResult PrintHtmlToPDFPageBreak()
    {
        StringBuilder sbBody = new StringBuilder();
        sbBody.Append("<html>");
        sbBody.Append("<body>");
        sbBody.Append("<p>This is first page</p>");
        sbBody.Append("<div style='page-break-before: always;'></div>");
        sbBody.Append("<p>This is second page</p>");
        sbBody.Append("</body>");
        sbBody.Append("</html>");
        string htmlContent = sbBody.ToString();
        bool isPortrait = true;
        string reportTitle = "Testing iText7 in .Net5";
        //generate the byte array for the Pdf
        byte[] pdfContent = null;
        //Create a System.IO.MemoryStream object
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //Initialize PDF writer
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(memoryStream);
            //Initialize PDF document
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
            //Initialize document
            Document document = (isPortrait ? new Document(pdfDocument, PageSize.LETTER) : new Document(pdfDocument, PageSize.LETTER.Rotate()));
            var headerHeight = String.IsNullOrEmpty(reportTitle) ? 70f : 120f;
            document.SetMargins(headerHeight, 10f, 56f, 10f); //top, right, bottom, left
            #region HTML to PDF
            //Convert to Elements
            ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
            IList<IElement> elements = HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(htmlContent, converterProperties);
            foreach (var element in elements)
                document.Add((IBlockElement)element);
            #endregion
            //Close the Document
            document.Close();
            pdfContent = memoryStream.ToArray();
            //Close the MemoryStream
            memoryStream.Close();
        }
        //return the byte array in the form of FileContentResult for browser download
        var fileName = "ConvertHtmlToPDF.pdf";
        return File(pdfContent, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, fileName);
    }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't attached the stacktrace but I am pretty sure the problem is in these two lines:

```
foreach (var element in elements)
   document.Add((IBlockElement)element);
```

You are just casting without checking whether the cast is legitimate. Just process the case when an element is an instance of `AreaBreak`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Alexey your solution worked.

Old code:

```
foreach (var element in elements)
         document.Add((IBlockElement)element);
```

New code:

```
foreach (var element in elements)
{
     if (element.GetType().Name == "HtmlPageBreak")  
        document.Add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));  
     else  
        document.Add((IBlockElement)element);  
}
```